# Weather App React taking three clicks to update state and pass props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-animated-weather

For my weather app, the goal is to let the user enter the latitude and longitude and see an eight day forecast. It works, but i have to click submit three times for the data to fetch correctly.

Currently working on making sure the API only calls when the user clicks submit. Not sure if I need the onclick with onsubmit, but it seems to be the only way the API fetch doesn't call each time the user types something.

weatherView: Where the user enters the info and sends it as a prop.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WeatherCard } from './weatherCard';

export class WeatherView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: "",
            long: "",
            valueLat: "",
            valueLong: "",
            check: false,
            latLongBool: false,
            latLong: ""
        }
        this.onChangeLat = this.onChangeLat.bind(this);
        this.onChangeLong = this.onChangeLong.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeLat = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            valueLat: e.target.value,
            check: false        
        });
    }

    onChangeLong = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            valueLong: e.target.value,
            check: false
        });
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (this.state.valueLat === " " || this.state.valueLong === " ") {
            alert("You must enter something");
        } 
            this.setState({
                lat: this.state.valueLat,
                latLongBool: true,
                long: this.state.valueLong
            })
            console.log("lat and long stored")

    }



     onClick = (e) => {


            this.setState({
                latLong: this.state.lat + "," + this.state.long,
                check: true

            })
            console.log("Prop to send " + this.state.latLong)

    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextState) {
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate activated 1');
    return this.state.latLong !== nextState.latLong;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to the Weather App!</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    Enter the Latitude in decimal format: <input type="text" name="lat" value={this.state.valueLat} onChange={this.onChangeLat}/> 
                    <br/>
                    Enter the Longitude in decimal format: <input type="text" name="long" value={this.state.valueLong} onChange={this.onChangeLong}/> 
                    <br/>
                    <button onClick={this.onClick} >Submit</button>
                </form>
                <WeatherCard latLong = {this.state.latLong} check={this.state.check}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

weatherCard:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactAnimatedWeather from 'react-animated-weather';


const defaults = [
{
    icon: 'CLEAR_DAY',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'CLEAR_NIGHT',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'CLOUDY',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'RAIN',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'SLEET',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'SNOW',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'WIND',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
},
{
    icon: 'FOG',
    color: 'white',
    size: 175,
    animate: true
}
];


function iconConverter(arg){
    switch (arg) {
        case 'clear-day': return 0;
            break;
        case 'clear-night': return 1;
            break;
        case 'partly-cloudy-day': return 2;
            break;
        case 'partly-cloudy-night': return 3;
            break;
        case 'cloudy': return 4;
            break;
        case 'rain': return 5;
            break;
        case 'sleet': return 6;
            break;
        case 'snow': return 7;
            break;
        case 'wind': return 8;
            break;
        case 'fog': return 9;
            break;

    }
}

const WCard = ({day, high, low, humidity, summary, sunrise, sunset, windspeed, time, rainProb, icon}) =>{
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{time}</p>
            <div id='wCardIcon'>

                <ReactAnimatedWeather

                    icon={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].icon}
                    color={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].color}
                    size={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].size}
                    animate={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].animate}
                  />
                <div>
                    <p>&#8679; {high}&#8457;</p>
                    <p>{low}&#8457; &#8681;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="wCardSum">{summary}</p>
            <p>Humidity: {humidity}%</p>
            <p>Wind speed: {windspeed}mph</p>
            <p>Sunrise: {sunrise}</p>
            <p>Sunset: {sunset}</p>
            <p>Chance of rain: {rainProb}%</p>

        </div>
    )};



// const weatherAPI = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/926bb6de03f1ae8575d48aaeb2fc9b83/34.0522,-118.2437';

const weatherAPI = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/926bb6de03f1ae8575d48aaeb2fc9b83/';

export class WeatherCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            requestFailed: false,
            info: '',
            latLongSubmitted: false,
            latLongValue: this.props.latLong,
            weatherAPI: 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/926bb6de03f1ae8575d48aaeb2fc9b83/'
        }
    }   



    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if (this.props.check) {
        console.log("Receive Props activated")
        console.log("Prop: " + this.props.latLong)
        console.log("Value for API" + this.latLongValue)

        if(this.props.latLong !== nextProps.latLong) {
            this.setState({
                latLongValue: nextProps.latLong,
                latLongSubmitted: true
            })      
            console.log(this.latLongValue)
        }

            console.log('componentDidMount is running')
            fetch(this.state.weatherAPI + this.state.latLongValue)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error("Network request failed")
                }
                return response;
            })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    info: data
                })
                console.log(data)
            }, () => {
                this.setState({
                requestFailed: true
                })
            })
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        console.log('shouldComponentUpdate activated 2');
    return this.state.latLongValue !== nextProps.latLongValue;
    }




    timeDateConverter(tempTime) {
        var time = tempTime *1000;
        var d = new Date(time);
        var formattedDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();

        return formattedDate
    }

    removeMilitary(hours){ 

        if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
            hours = "" + hours;
        } else if (hours > 12) {
            hours = "" + (hours - 12);
        } else if (hours === 0) {
            hours= "12";
        }
        return hours;
    }

    timeConverter(tempTime) {
        var time = tempTime *1000;
        var d = new Date(time);
        var hours = d.getHours();
        if (hours>=12){                 //Adding endings
                var suffix = "P.M.";}
            else{
                suffix = "A.M.";}
        var minutes = (d.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();

        hours = this.removeMilitary(hours);

        var formattedTime = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;

        return formattedTime;
    }


    render() {
        if (!this.state.latLongSubmitted) return <p>Waiting for coordinates... try 34.0522, -118.2437</p>
        // if (this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed</p>
        if (!this.state.info) return <p>Loading...</p>
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>The current temperature in {this.state.info.timezone} is: {this.state.info.currently.apparentTemperature}&#8457;.</h1>
                <h1>The 8 day forecast for {this.state.info.timezone}:</h1>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.info.daily.data.map((day, id) => 
                        <div key={{id}>{day}} id="weatherCard">
                            <WCard time={this.timeDateConverter(day.time)}
                                high={day.temperatureHigh}
                                low={day.temperatureLow}
                                summary={day.summary}
                                icon={day.icon}
                                humidity={day.humidity}
                                sunrise={this.timeConverter(day.sunriseTime)}
                                sunset={this.timeConverter(day.sunsetTime)}
                                rainProb={day.precipProbability}
                                windspeed={day.windSpeed}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </ul>

                <a href="https://darksky.net/poweredby/">Powered by DarkSky</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach the problem with three components. I have re-write some of your components. I removed unnecessary state props and code. You can copy and paste then try to analyse the code. I am here if you have any question

WeatherApp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WeatherForm } from './WeatherForm';
import { WeatherCard } from './WeatherCard';

export class WeatherApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: 0,
            long: 0,
        }
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit = (lat, long) => {
        this.setState({
          lat,
          long
        });
    }


    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <WeatherForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
            <WeatherCard lat={this.state.lat} long={this.state.long}/>
          </div>

        )
    }
}
```

WeatherForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class WeatherForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          lat: 0,
          long: 0,
      }
      this.onChangeLat = this.onChangeLat.bind(this);
      this.onChangeLong = this.onChangeLong.bind(this);
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeLat = (e) => {

      let value = e.target.value;
      if(!isNaN(value) ){
        this.setState({
            lat: e.target.value
        });
      }
  }

  onChangeLong = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    if(!isNaN(value) ){
      this.setState({
          long: e.target.value
      });
    }
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.lat.length == 0 || this.state.long.length == 0) {
        alert("You must enter something");
    }else{
      this.props.onSubmit(this.state.lat, this.state.long)
    }

  }

  render() {
      return(
          <div>
              <h1>Welcome to the Weather App!</h1>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                  Enter the Latitude in decimal format: <input type="text" name="lat" value={this.state.lat} onChange={this.onChangeLat}/>
                  <br/>
                  Enter the Longitude in decimal format: <input type="text" name="long" value={this.state.long} onChange={this.onChangeLong}/>
                  <br/>
                  <button >Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

WeatherCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactAnimatedWeather from 'react-animated-weather';


const defaults = [
  {
      icon: 'CLEAR_DAY',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'CLEAR_NIGHT',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'CLOUDY',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'RAIN',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'SLEET',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'SNOW',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'WIND',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  },
  {
      icon: 'FOG',
      color: 'white',
      size: 175,
      animate: true
  }
];

function iconConverter(arg){
    switch (arg) {
        case 'clear-day': return 0;
            break;
        case 'clear-night': return 1;
            break;
        case 'partly-cloudy-day': return 2;
            break;
        case 'partly-cloudy-night': return 3;
            break;
        case 'cloudy': return 4;
            break;
        case 'rain': return 5;
            break;
        case 'sleet': return 6;
            break;
        case 'snow': return 7;
            break;
        case 'wind': return 8;
            break;
        case 'fog': return 9;
            break;

    }
}

const WCard = ({day, high, low, humidity, summary, sunrise, sunset, windspeed, time, rainProb, icon}) =>{
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{time}</p>
            <div id='wCardIcon'>

                <ReactAnimatedWeather

                    icon={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].icon}
                    color={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].color}
                    size={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].size}
                    animate={defaults[iconConverter(icon)].animate}
                  />
                <div>
                    <p>&#8679; {high}&#8457;</p>
                    <p>{low}&#8457; &#8681;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="wCardSum">{summary}</p>
            <p>Humidity: {humidity}%</p>
            <p>Wind speed: {windspeed}mph</p>
            <p>Sunrise: {sunrise}</p>
            <p>Sunset: {sunset}</p>
            <p>Chance of rain: {rainProb}%</p>

        </div>
    )};

export class WeatherCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            requestFailed: false,
            info: undefined,
            latLongValue: this.props.latLong
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.fetchData(this.props.lat, this.props.long);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
       this.fetchData(nextProps.lat, nextProps.long);
    }

    timeDateConverter(tempTime) {
        var time = tempTime *1000;
        var d = new Date(time);
        var formattedDate = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();

        return formattedDate
    }

    removeMilitary(hours){

        if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
            hours = "" + hours;
        } else if (hours > 12) {
            hours = "" + (hours - 12);
        } else if (hours === 0) {
            hours= "12";
        }
        return hours;
    }

    timeConverter(tempTime) {
        var time = tempTime *1000;
        var d = new Date(time);
        var hours = d.getHours();
        if (hours>=12){                 //Adding endings
                var suffix = "P.M.";}
            else{
                suffix = "A.M.";}
        var minutes = (d.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();

        hours = this.removeMilitary(hours);

        var formattedTime = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;

        return formattedTime;
    }

    fetchData(lat, long){
      const weatherRequest = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/fbdca57e2ef5b4ac0f12e3d3779f090e/${lat},${long}`;
      console.log(weatherRequest);
      fetch(weatherRequest).then( data => data.json() ).then( data => {
            this.setState({
                info: data,
                requestFailed: true
            });
        }, () => {
            this.setState({
            requestFailed: true
            })
      })
    }


    render() {
        return(
            this.state.info ? (<div>
                <h1>The current temperature in {this.state.info.timezone} is: {this.state.info.currently.apparentTemperature}</h1>
                <h1>The 8 day forecast for {this.state.info.timezone}:</h1>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.info.daily.data.map((day, id) =>
                        <div key={'_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)} id="weatherCard">
                            <WCard time={this.timeDateConverter(day.time)}
                                high={day.temperatureHigh}
                                low={day.temperatureLow}
                                summary={day.summary}
                                icon={day.icon}
                                humidity={day.humidity}
                                sunrise={this.timeConverter(day.sunriseTime)}
                                sunset={this.timeConverter(day.sunsetTime)}
                                rainProb={day.precipProbability}
                                windspeed={day.windSpeed}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </ul>

                <a href="https://darksky.net/poweredby/">Powered by DarkSky</a>

            </div>
          ) : <div>Loading</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so.. there's a lot to address here but let's start with the heart of the problem:

Inside WeatherCard you have this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (this.props.check)
```

Of course this will not fire the first time because you're checking old props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (nextProps.check) {
```

Magic! It works.

Ok but.. let's fix up some other things.

1) You're already using class properties (`method = e =>`) so you can drop a lot of cruft:

this whole block:

```
class WeatherView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lat: "",
        long: "",
        valueLat: "",
        valueLong: "",
        check: false,
        latLongBool: false,
        latLong: ""
    }
    this.onChangeLat = this.onChangeLat.bind(this);
    this.onChangeLong = this.onChangeLong.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
```

can be replaced with:

```
class WeatherView extends React.Component {
  state = {
      lat: "",
      long: "",
      valueLat: "",
      valueLong: "",
      check: false,
      latLongBool: false,
      latLong: ""
  }
```

You only need to bind stuff if you're not using arrow functions, so that's one thing.

2) You don't need duplicate states for input values and the thing those input values turn into. You can completely drop `state.valueLong` and `state.valueLong`.. you only need `state.lat` and `state.long`.

With that in mind you can drop the `<form>` and `onSubmit` entirely.

**BREAKING:** my computer is dying. I have to finish this answer when I get home, but I will write more.

In the meantime you can see a mostly fixed version here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hrfmuh?file=WeatherView.js the api call doesn't work but stuff fires like you would expect

Answer (score -1):

add the attribute type="submit" to your button

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```